# How to use a dynamic selection of column names to sum in a select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I think I may be approaching this all wrong so if I am please let me know!

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Id | Region |  0 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50
-----------------------------------------
01 | London | 24 | 45 | 38 | 29 | 36 | 49
-----------------------------------------
02 | Bham   | 27 | 42 | 33 | 31 | 38 | 41 
-----------------------------------------
03 | Lpool  | 23 | 38 | 29 | 31 | 34 | 49
```

Where a row represents a region followed by populations in the age ranges 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 etc. I would like to be able to select a sum of the population for a given age range. E.G. for 10-40:

```
SELECT (p.10 + p.20 + p.30) FROM Population p WHERE Id = 01
```

How do I go about doing this with a custom range? E.g. a stored procedure that takes in a min and max value for the age range. The SP isn't the problem, just the ability to dynamically define a range of columns to sum.

Comment: In that case it would perhaps be better to construct a table `Population (Id, Region, Age)` and thus display the numbers in rows, instead of several columns.

Comment: This was my thinking too but I have the data in a nice CSV organised in this current format and am even more unsure how to go trough the process of transforming it! If I don't get any answers I may have to bite the bullet and take your advice!

Comment: You will probably bite more bullets in the long run if you don't take that advice.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters who suggest unpivoting the data. I don't think there is a good answer to the question as posed.

Answer (score 0):

You can give another condition using 'AND' operation
and you are doing wrong

```
SELECT (p.10 + p.20 + p.30) FROM Population p WHERE Id = 01
```

you are missing either underscore between population p.  Something else
try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  BETWEEN 10 and 40 AND id=id_no
```

Comment: The notation `FROM Population p` is valid SQL; it gives the table alias `p` to `Population`, so that the `p.column` notation can be used.  The names like `p.10` are dubious because `10` isn't a valid column name.  In MySQL, you'd probably have to enclose the name in back-ticks: ```p.`10`…``` (which is hell in MarkDown), or in standard SQL, you'd use a delimited identifier `p."10"` — or you'd rename the column to a valid name like `ages_0_9`, `ages_10_19` or some such scheme.

Answer (score -1):

if you wants to select in a custom range the query is like this:-
    select * from 
    where  between   and ;

Comment: But that's for **rows**, here the **columns** should be between 0 and 10.