# Pivot data from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

Following on from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329377/how-to-use-a-dynamic-selection-of-column-names-to-sum-in-a-select-query/43329746#43329746) and some useful advice.

I currently have a table where the columns are age ranges (0-10, 10-20 etc.) and contain an integer population value.

I have created a new table into which I would like to pivot the data from the first table and insert it into the new table where one row from the first table would require seven rows in the new table. E.G. for one row:

```
Id | Region |  0 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50
-----------------------------------------
01 | London | 24 | 45 | 38 | 29 | 36 | 49
```

becomes

```
Id | Region | AgeRange | Population
-----------------------------------
 1 |   1    |     0    |     24
 2 |   1    |    10    |     45
 3 |   1    |    20    |     38
```

(and the rest of the rows but you get the idea)

How would it be suggested that I go about doing this?

Comment: Is the number of column fixed?

Comment: In other words, is there really just 0-50 or even more columns like 0-100 or 0-1000 as solution varies.

Comment: The number of columns is fixed. In the actual table it goes up in 5's to 95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `UNION ALL` to  unpivot your columns, then use variables to assign an row_number or id

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FWBW80170)**

```
SELECT t.*, @id := @id + 1 as  rn
FROM (
    SELECT Region, 0 AgeRange, `0` as Population
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Region, 10 as AgeRange,`10` as Population
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Region, 20 as AgeRange, `20` asPopulation
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Region, 30 as AgeRange, `30` asPopulation
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Region, 40 as AgeRange, `40` asPopulation
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Region, 50 as AgeRange, `50` asPopulation
    FROM YourTable
 ) t
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT @id := 0) var
ORDER BY Region, AgeRange
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm just struggling to understand what's going on here. Is this selecting from the new table that I'm trying to populate as it has the AgeRange and Population fields?